# ggplot2 - area fill is incorrectly plotting the area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I thought this was a problem with the ordering of how I was placing each aestetic. Here is the relevant code.

[image]

Sort of like a normal distribution. Going to melt it down and plot each distribution.

```
 df <- as.data.frame(r_data_frame)
 names(df) <- c('Length','Unique','Donor Unique','All')
 library(ggplot2)
 library(reshape2)
 ndf <- melt(df,id.vars='Length')
 print(ndf)
 graph <- ggplot(data=ndf) + geom_area(aes(Length,value,fill=variable)) +
     theme_bw()+
     xlim(1,42)+
     geom_hline(yintercept=2369802) +
     geom_hline(yintercept=2469225,color='red')+
     geom_vline(xintercept=15)

 plot(graph)
```

The melted data frame is probably better found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jwillis0720/8326854)

Here is the output

[image]

The problem I'm having is that the shaded areas don't seem to be plotted correctly. I plotted the horizontal lines for both "Donor Unique" and "Unique" of where they should be according to the data frame. "Unique" is right as it is right at its y value. However "Donor Unique" is way to high. They should barely overlap. If you look at the values What in the world is going on? Should I be using something else besides geom_area?

Comment: Have you tried `position="dodge"` in `geom_area(...)`?

Comment: Yes that worked along with putting them in the right order

Comment: If you submit that as an answer I will gladly accept

Comment: @jihoward if you write the answer i can accept

Comment: Usually you get notified of a comment thread no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `position="dodge"` in the call to `geom_area(...)`.

Many of the `geom_*` functions in `ggplot`, including `geom_area(...)`, `geom_histogram(...)`, and `geom_bar(...)`, have a position parameter. The default is (usually...) "stacked", which creates geometries that are additive. To display the geometries with independent y-values, use position="dodge".